# htaccess wordpress/index.php rewrite rule

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have put my wordpress files inside a folder wordpress instead of root.
I am able to access my site as `www.example.com/wordpress`
But i want to access it as  `www.example.com,` want to hide wordpress in url.
my .htaccess file  is as

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Your question is how to make an internal URL (between pages, menu naviagion), without FOLDER_NAME, or your .htaccess throw an error/ not working at all? Please clarify situation.

Comment: no internal url are working also, i just want to access subfolder wordpress as root by htaccess

Comment: Did you follow the http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory when installing wordpress on?

Comment: i tried with Pointing your home site's URL to a subdirectory no succes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add this to the .htaccess in your *root directory*:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*) wordpress/($1) [NC,L]
```